# Sails.js associations populate with different connections

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have two models

countries - from mysql server

```
Country = {
   tableName: 'countries',
   connection: 'someMysqlServer',

   schema: true,
   migrate: 'safe',
   autoCreatedAt: false,
   autoUpdatedAt: false,

   attributes: {
    country_id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    ....
  }
};

User = {
    connection: 'somePostgresqlServer',

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

        country_id: {
            model: 'country'
        },
```

$> User.findOneById(1).populate('country_id').exec(console.log)

and get error

```
sails> Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Unable to determine primary key for collection `countries` because an error was encountered acquiring the collection definition:
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'definition' of undefined]
  at _getPK (/projects/foturist-server/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:923:13)
  at StrategyPlanner.__FIND__.Cursor.$getPK (/projects/foturist-server/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:504:20)
.....

Details:  Error: Unable to determine primary key for collection `countries` because an error was encountered acquiring the collection definition:
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'definition' of undefined]
```

Why country association uses with postgre-connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the two models are on different database connections, you're not going to be able to do an actual SQL join. I would think what you'd need is a

```
User.find({id: 1}).exec(function(user) { 
    var theUser = user;
    Country.find(user.country_id)
    .exec(function(country) {
        theUser.country = country;
        return theUser;
    }); });
```

I'm not sure what specific needs you're trying to address, but since a lookup table of countries is unlikely to frequently change, and is in an entirely different data store, I would suggest caching this data in something like Redis or Memcache. Then on your User find callback you can fetch the country by id from your cache store. This will be much faster unless you expect this data to change on a regular basis. You could write a service that does a lazy lookup in your other database and serves from the cache then on, or cache them all up front when your app launches.

Comment: thanks for the answer
but i if uses {rest: true} , then this code will be generated "automatically".

About  service lookup - i think. Elasticsearch